# Login using google in asp.net 4 with SocialAuth-net

Tags: c#, asp.net, socialauth

I am trying to implement social auth from the following [link](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/wiki/Integration_Guide). But I am getting error on the config section of web.config, the following lines in the example:

```
<configSections>...
    <section name="SocialAuthConfiguration" type="Brickred.!SocialAuth.NET.Core.SocialAuthConfiguration,SocialAuth,Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowLocation="true" />
</configSections>
```

The system could not find the type, whereas I have added all the binaries and referenced them. Kindly help!!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `!` in your type string; what does that mean, or is that a typo?  Try removing it maybe?

Comment: No, its as it is given in the reference integration site. Anyways i have tried removing that skeptical ! but got the same error. Could not load file or assembly....

Comment: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for SocialAuthConfiguration: Could not load file or assembly 'SocialAuth, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Is a SocialAuth DLL in your bin directory, and does its version match what you have in your config file?

Comment: Yes its in bin directory and is the version that i have downloaded from [here](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/downloads/list)

Comment: Maybe the "or one of its dependencies" portion of the error message is relevant.  According to Reflector, that DLL is dependent on log4net, Microsoft.IdentityModel, and Newtonsoft.Json; are all of *those* in the bin directory?

Comment: Yes I have copied all the 4 dlls in the bin directory.

Comment: Are you targeting the .NET 4.0 framework?

Comment: yes i m working on asp.net 4 in visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace it with:

```
<section name="SocialAuthConfiguration" type="Brickred.SocialAuth.NET.Core.SocialAuthConfiguration,SocialAuth-net,Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowLocation="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have all of the DLLs in place, yet they still can't load.  Since the DLLs were downloaded from the Internet, you may need to "unblock" them; they may not be loading due to security reasons.

For each DLL:

1. Right-click on the DLL
2. Click on "Properties"
3. In the General tab, click "Unblock"

Comment: No, there is no such option as unblock. But I had followed referencing with the following steps:

1. Right-Click on my project in VS
2. Add reference
3. Selected 4 dll's

Comment: According to Reflector, the assembly's title is SocialAuth-net; can you try that instead of SocialAuth for the assembly name?

Comment: In fact, in the page you linked to, this is how it has the section defined: `<section name="SocialAuthConfiguration" type="Brickred.SocialAuth.NET.Core.SocialAuthConfiguration, SocialAuth-net, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowLocation="true" />`

Comment: Note that there is no `!`, and the assembly name is "SocialAuth-net"

Comment: Hi,

I have done the whole process again, added the references, removed !, but kept the name same SocialAuth. This time it finally worked but I am stucked with other problems now. Please have a look at [the problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299991/login-using-google-yahoo-msn-socialauth-net-problem).