# Login using google, yahoo, msn: SocialAuth-net problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, yahoo, msn

I am using social auth-net for integration google, yahoo & msn login in asp.net 4. I am using [this link](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/wiki/Integration_Guide) for development.

On integrating there are some errors with each of the services:

1. Google login works fine but redirects me to the homepage everytime when i gave a redirect page on the login method: oUser.Login("Google.aspx");
2. Yahoo login works till yahoo login page but after login, is not redirected to the website, rather stucked with an //authsub... url.
3. Msn login: Msn says that there is a problem with the site with whom you are trying to share information.

I have hosted the above demonstration page [here](http://www.eprocerp.com/rough.aspx). Kindly help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detailed thread on these issues is available here:

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/issues/detail?id=4\

Summary:

1. Google Problem: Feature yet to be implemented
2. Yahoo Problem: Access to profile is required
3. MSN Problem: Likely account problem

Comment: Yep. I am the same person who posted this problem for discussion at the given link :)